# Puppeteer & browserWSEndpoint: can't upload files dynamically

Tags: javascript, web-services, headless-browser, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying puppeteer and browserless/chrome (https://hub.docker.com/r/browserless/chrome) to test some automation scripts. I'm currently just running a browserless/chrome instance locally, connecting puppeteer to it with **browserWSEndpoint**.

It's all running locally, all in the same machine.

Everything pretty much works except the file upload code.
Without the browserless connection (just launching puppeteer and a chromium instance) the code can upload the images without a problem, however, when relaying it to a the websocket, it apparently can't find the files, even if I supply the full path.

Here is the code i'm using:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
    browserWSEndpoint: 'ws://localhost:32769',
    headless: true
})
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('http://localhost:8080', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

// Do some things

let testUpload = async () => {
    const upload = await page.$("input");
    await upload.uploadFile('test.jpg');
    await page.screenshot({path: 'test_s_'+Date.now()+'.png'});
}

// Do more things
```

I'm 100% sure the DOM exists at that point, and that the file exists, in the same folder.

Any pointing in the right direction is very helpfull.

Cheers!

Comment: any luck founding a solution here? I am facing same issue

Answer (score 2):

How far does it run before you hit a problem?
Does it get to the first '//some stuff' bit?
Ive had some trouble in the past using `'networkidle2'` and as of 1.0.0 it looks as though its been removed

Comment: I don't really hit problems with this setup until I try and upload the images through the webservice.
The `networkidle` tag is the only one that actually work with me, after a few tests.

Comment: It still doesnt solve the issue, now instead of `networkidle`, `networkidle2` is introduced. What can we do to upload local files to the web dynamically. What if I have a 100 files in a local system, then what syntax is needed to be followed to upload them all, or do I have to run a loop for each and every file making the code more complex.

Comment: Plus I am super new to this, I just tried to use this syntax from JS or Gulp etc. => `/directory/*.jpg`, and the error saying `/directory/*.jpg` is not found. So in this case, what should be done? Usually, all syntax have this feature in there API.